# Slow Join on Composite Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization

I have the following query, its runtime is ~2 seconds until I join `ProductStores` on `StoreID` which increases it to ~3 minutes, joining only on ProductID keeps it at  ~2 seconds.

```
SELECT
    Enabled = pp.PspEnabled
    , StockStatusID = ss.ID
    , WebSellable = pp.PspWebSellable
    , CSSellable = pp.PspCsSellable
FROM 
    #ExternalProducts pp 
JOIN 
    Product p ON p.ExternalCode = pp.code
JOIN 
    Stores s ON s.Name = pp.p_externalStore
JOIN 
    StockStatus ss ON ss.Name = pp.PspStockStatus
JOIN 
    ProductStores ps ON (/* Store join increases time only */ ps.StoreID = s.ID AND ps.ProductID = p.ID)
```

**Rows**:

- Stores: 108
- Product: 136'598
- ProductStores: 609'963

**Keys**:

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Stores] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Product] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)   
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ProductStores] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductID] ASC, [StoreID] ASC)

CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ProductStores_dbo.Stores_SiteID] 
    FOREIGN KEY([StoreID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Stores] ([ID])
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ProductStores_dbo.Product_ProductID] 
    FOREIGN KEY([ProductID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([ID])
```

**Execution Plan**:

The execution plan shows the bulk cost is coming from a Hash Match (Inner Join) with a Hash Keys Probe `[dbo].[Stores].Name` and Hash Keys Build `[#ExternalProducts].p_externalstore` which I assume is the problem but I'm not sure how to interpret this?

[image: execution plan 1]

[image: execution plan 2]

[image: hash join]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't believe that you actually have the index on `ProductStores`.

Comment: Doing a `SELECT * FROM sys.indexes ...` shows me it has `PX_dbo.ProductStores CLUSTERED`, `IX_ProductID NONCLUSTERED`, `IX_StoreID NONCLUSTERED`.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan?  Also did you run that query in the tuning adviser?  What is in the temp table?

Comment: I've added them as pictures, wasn't sure what the preferred format was. I have not I'll look into that thanks.

Comment: Which columns from `ProductStores` are you using? You can [include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) them in your index to improve performance. Either way, your reported query time (~3 minutes) is too long. Try to create an index on the `#ExternalProducts` table - it won't help directly, but may help query optimizer to generate a better plan.

Comment: "Estimated Number of Rows" very different from "Actual Number of Rows". I think that you need to update statistics for your tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denis Rubashkin noted that the estimated and actual row numbers are actually very different. After the `UPDATE STATISTICS` failed to modify the execution plan I reorganised the query to pull from `ProductStores` and filter from `#ExternalProducts` instead which allowed me to force a Nested Loop Join (which I assumed would be preferable on smaller result sets).

```
SELECT
    Enabled = pp.PspEnabled
    , StockStatusID = ss.ID
    , WebSellable = pp.PspWebSellable
    , CSSellable = pp.PspCsSellable
FROM ProductStores ps
JOIN Product p ON p.ID = ps.ProductID
JOIN Stores s ON s.ID = ps.StoreID
INNER LOOP JOIN #ExternalProducts pp ON (p.Code = pp.Code AND s.Name = pp.p_externalstore)
JOIN StockStatus ss ON ss.Name = pp.PspStockStatus
```

This reduced the query time to ~7 seconds from ~3 minutes which is acceptable for this purpose!